# Fibonacci, imprime el 1 dos veces consecutivas

Tags: python, fibonacci

Estoy empezando a estudiar Python y estoy haciendo la serie de Fibonacci utilizando solo el bucle **While**; pude lograr que se imprima la serie correctamente, pero me hicieron la pregunta del como es que se imprime el **1** dos veces consecutivas utilizando el codigo que tengo, pero no logro descifrar eso.

```
N1,N2=1,0
while N2<=100:
    print(N2)
    N1,N2 = N1+N2,N1
```

Mi logica es la siguiente:

```
N1 = 1
N2 = 0
Mientras N2 <= 100:
**Imprime** N2 = 0
N1 = 1 + 0
N2 = 1

**Imprime** N2 = 1
N1 = 1 + 1
N2 = 2

**Imprime** N2 = 2
N1 = 1 + 2
N2 = 3
```

Ya a partir de aca, la suma de la serie esta correcta, pero no me da (logicamente) el por que se imprime 0, 1, **1**, 2, 3, 5... etc.

Gracias de antemano por la aclaracion.

Answer (score 1):

La sucesión que te sale es correcta, pero tu razonamiento de que el 1 debería aparecer una sola vez está mal.

Señalo seguidamente el error en tu razonamiento:

```
N1 = 1
N2 = 0
Mientras N2 <= 100:
**Imprime** N2 = 0
N1 = 1 + 0
N2 = 1       <-- Bien, este era el anterior valor de N1

**Imprime** N2 = 1
N1 = 1 + 1
N2 = 2      <--  MAL. El anterior valor de N1 era 1, por tanto aqui
                 N2 tomará el valor 1

**Imprime** N2 = 1  <-- Y por tanto imprime 1 dos veces
N1 = 1 + 2
N2 = 3      <-- De nuevo MAL, pues el anterior valor de N1 era 2
```

Como ves el problema es que la instrucción:

```
N1, N2 = N1+N2, N1
```

asigna a la vez ambos valores, por tanto lo que se asigna a `N2` es lo que `N1` tenía **antes**, y no lo que tendría tras asignarle `N1+N2`. Para hacer esto segundo tendría que ser:

```
N1 = N1+N2
N2 = N1
```

pero esto estaría mal pues no generaría correctamente la sucesión de Fibonacci.

Comment: OK! Creo que entiendo la logica ahora. Al guardarse el valor anterior de N1, ese es el que se imprime (en N2). Muchas gracias por la aclaracion!